# React useReducer not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I'm using `useReducer` to update the `errorsState` when user logged in and failed. I've read many solutions and it was said that `dispatch` is async and I know that so I put `console.log` inside the `useEffect` to see the `errorsState` change, but unfortunately it didn't changed. Here's my code

Login.jsx

```js
export default function Login({ userProps }) {
  //
  // some variables and state
  //
  const { loading, user } = useLogin({ email: state.email }, state.submitted)
  const [errors, dispatch] = useReducer(errorsReducer, errorsState)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("errors", errors) // it won't triggered because errors state didn't updating from UseLogin
  }, [errors])

  return content
}
```

Here is fetch function `useLogin`

AuthAction.js

```js
export const useLogin = (data, submitted) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, userState)
  const [errors, errorsDispatch] = useReducer(errorsReducer, errorsState)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!submitted) return

    dispatch({
      type: USER_ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST,
    })

    ticketApi.login(data).then(({ res, status }) => {
      if (status !== "failed") {
        // Save to local storage
        const { token } = res
        // set token to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token)
        // Set token to Auth Header
        setAuthToken(token)
        // decode token to get user data with jwt-decode
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        // set current user
        return dispatch({
          type: USER_ACTIONS.GET_USER,
          payload: decoded,
        })
      }

      dispatch({
        type: USER_ACTIONS.END_REQUEST,
      })

      return errorsDispatch({
        type: ERRORS_ACTIONS.GET_ERRORS,
        payload: res.response.data,
      })
    })
  }, [submitted])

  return state
}
```

I've tried put `console.log` inside the `ERRORS_ACTIONS.GET_ERRORS` to see the response, and it was fine.
So where did i go wrong?

Comment: I think you may be calling `useReducer` on two different error states. Dispatching actions on one, inspecting the other.

Comment: I think it was the correct one. because there's no other `errors` variable except from the `errorsReducer`

Comment: I know it sounds silly but ... your custom hook is capitalized, it should start with lowercase `use`, try changing that

Comment: nothing changes, still won't works

Comment: where does `errorsState` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useReducer` allows you to better manage complex states, it's not a state container, what you're doing there is to create 2 different states, one inside `useLogin` and the other in your `Login` component, return `errors` from your `useLogin` hook so the Login component can see it.

Login

```js
export default function Login({ userProps }) {
  //
  // some variables and state
  //
  const { loading, user, errors } = useLogin({ email: state.email }, state.submitted)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("errors", errors)
  }, [errors])

  return content
}
```

useLogin

```js
export const useLogin = (data, submitted) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, userState)
  const [errors, errorsDispatch] = useReducer(errorsReducer, errorsState)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!submitted) return

    dispatch({
      type: USER_ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST,
    })

    ticketApi.login(data).then(({ res, status }) => {
      if (status !== "failed") {
        // Save to local storage
        const { token } = res
        // set token to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token)
        // Set token to Auth Header
        setAuthToken(token)
        // decode token to get user data with jwt-decode
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        // set current user
        return dispatch({
          type: USER_ACTIONS.GET_USER,
          payload: decoded,
        })
      }

      dispatch({
        type: USER_ACTIONS.END_REQUEST,
      })

      return errorsDispatch({
        type: ERRORS_ACTIONS.GET_ERRORS,
        payload: res.response.data,
      })
    })
  }, [submitted])

  return { ...state, errors };
}
```

Comment: yeah that's make sense. I thought that `useReducer` would work same as `redux`. Big thank you but I already moved to using `redux`